Do service panels in new homes in Texas need to be grounded?
Is there an NEC code that explains if a NEW construction breaker box is installed in a NEW house construction, it has to be grounded (not replacing an old breaker box)? In other words, doesn't a new construction home need to be grounded by the electrician that installed all of the house wiring and breaker box for it to be a complete job, or can he just say that whoever later connects either a solar system or grid power has to ground his breaker box installation or that I can pay him additional money later to come install the ground rod and ground wire?
The closest I got was NEC 250.53 (a)(3) but that's just about the rods themselves, not the need for the breaker box to be grounded.

It seems odd.  Grounding the box is running a ground wire to the rods/UFER.  About the easiest job in wiring a house being built.  Pounding ground rods in the hot Texas sun is probably a job I would not want either.

Keep in mind that the latest NEC (which it appears Texas is using) requires an outside disconnect. That is normally done using a meter/main combination or a disconnect box right next to the meter. In both cases it usually (not so sure about "always") means the ground rod (or Ufer) wire goes to that outside box, and not to the "main" panel. The "main" panel inside the house is then technically a subpanel with ground and neutral separate and does not have a wire going to the ground rods/Ufer ground. So if you are referring to "the big everything panel inside the house" plus

"should it connect to the ground rods?" then the answer is NO. On the other hand, if you are referring to that outside disconnect/meter-main, or if you are referring to "grounding in general" and not "ground rods" then the answer is YES. Need more specifics. It sounds like you have a disagreement with an electrician (which can happen) but we need more specifics to decipher what is actually going on.

The breaker panel has 200amp main disconnect switch inside & is installed attached to an exterior wall. The electric Coop inspected & said I needed a ground at the breaker panel so the electrician just wanted to charge an additional $250 to install that $18 rod, $10 wire & $3 connector. The coop gave me 4/0 cable & I buried it and attached it at the meter on the pole and in the breaker box panel on the wall. I'm trying to find a NEC code that says that when you install a new panel or wire a new house, you must ground it or you're not finished. It's sandy & I installed the 8' rod in 2 minutes

pilot135pd you can edit pictures into the original post.   Hit "edit" in the row of words right below the keywords below the question text.

Because of the new disconnect switch requirement, it's tricky.
2020 code adds a requirement for an outside disconnect so firemen can stop getting hurt pulling meters under load. Typically the outside panel has only a disconnect or just a few things like solar, surge and generator interlock.  Then power goes onward to an inside panel that has "all your breakers".    This panel may or may not have a main breaker.
If it does not have a main breaker, that's that. The outside panel is the main breaker, the grounding point must be there, and 4-wire feeder must run from the outside panel to the inside.
If the interior panel does have a main breaker, so there's now a confusion between which one is your main breaker / service disconnect, this confusion must be resolved by labeling both breakers per NEC 230.85. This gives you the option to designate the outer one "only a disconnect" and declare the interior one to be the service disconnect / main breaker.  Now the grounding point is there, and service wire from the outside disconnect to the main can be 3-wire.
Now in that latter example, certain things are still allowed to be in the outside panel, per NEC 230.82.  Generator interlock, solar, surge suppressor, load management equipment etc.
But regardless, whereever you have designated the service disconnect, that's where ground originates and you need to tie that to ground rods per NEC.

The breaker panel I'm talking about has a 200amp main disconnect switch on the top and all the individual house breakers below it (a/c, kitchen lights, hallway lights, water heater, etc). That box is installed attached to the wall on the outside of the house. There's no other panel or switch inside of the house. Is there an NEC code that says that panel has to be grounded for the job to be complete and correct, or is it ok to just leave the grounding of the house to someone else to do eventually if someone catches it? Too bad I can't add pictures here.

@pilot135pd Yes it has to be grounded, but a big switch at the top of a panelboard is not the same thing as a main disconnect.  So without looking inside the panelboard, looking at the meter, and everything in between, we don't know what's going on there.

@pilot135pd Yes, it should be grounded, absolutely.

I know. Thanks for your help and time, I really appreciate it. SHOULD and SHALL are two different animals. I think I'll never find the answer.
Apparently electricians just ground it because they want to and not because NEC says something like "when wiring a new building you shall ground the electrical system" or something like that.
